# Soflayer Billing API user

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Can I only use the username of the softlayer master account and the API - key to get the billing information of each account through the API?Can't I get my billing information on my account?

Answer (score 0):

you can use any user of your account to get the billing information, you only need to make sure that the user has granted the permissions for that.